# Find the highest scoring word from a string according to its position in the alphabet using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split, array.prototype.map

I am trying to solve CodeWars challenges but I have a problem with this one:

"Given a string of words, you need to find the highest scoring word.
Each letter of a word scores points according to its position in the alphabet:

```
 a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 etc.
```

You need to return the highest scoring word as a string.
If two words score the same, return the word that appears earliest in the original string.
All letters will be lowercase and all inputs will be valid."

My code passed 104 cases but got wrong on 1 case.
The wrong answer test case is

```
'what time are we climbing up the volcano'
```

According to codewars - Expected: 'volcano', instead got: 'climbing'

Any ideas?

link of the problem - https://www.codewars.com/kata/57eb8fcdf670e99d9b000272/train/javascript

```
 function high(x){
  let result = '', value =0, counterValue = 0; 

  let splittedArray = x.split(' ');

  splittedArray.map(splitItem => {
    counterValue = 0;

    let splitItemArray = splitItem.split('');

    splitItemArray.map(splitChar => { 
      counterValue += splitChar.charCodeAt();
    })

    if(counterValue>value){
      result = splitItem;
      value = counterValue;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Your issue is your using charCodeAt which gives it's ascii value not in `1...` format you want

Comment: use an array storing all the alphabets and use indexOf, the error is due to charCodeAt

Comment: welp, there you go, 4 answers and 4 different ways to translate the alphabet into numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function high(x) {
  const words = x.split(' ');
  const alphabetMap = {};
  for (let i='a'.charCodeAt(), j = 1; i <= 'z'.charCodeAt(); i++, j++) {
    alphabetMap[i] = j;
  }
  let highestScoringWord = { word: '', score: 0 };
  words.forEach(w => {
    const chars = w.split('');
    const sumOfChars = chars.reduce((count, char) => count + alphabetMap[char.charCodeAt()], 0);
    if (sumOfChars > highestScoringWord.score) {
      highestScoringWord = { word: w, score: sumOfChars };
    }
  });

  return highestScoringWord.word;
}

console.log(high('what time are we climbing up the volcano')) // volcano ;)
```

Comment: I'm still not sure why your method with `charCodeAt` didn't work, but it works this way! :)

Comment: It worked & I understand your solution. But yes I still can't understand what's wrong with my solution .....

Thank you for helping

Comment: Surprised your solution works because it didn't appear to handle non-alphabetic character (like commas and periods), but it looks like at `count + alphabetMap[char.charCodeAt()]` since something like a comma isn't in the alphabetMap it returns `undefined` and `count + undefined` is just `count` so it works. Not sure if that was intentional or just lucky. But I don't see where this solution handles the secondary requirement of `If two words score the same, return the word that appears earliest in the original string.`

Comment: My last comment was incorrect, this solution actually should definitely not work; `count + undefine` is `NaN` not `undefined` so it will error against more rigorous testing. Easy to fix, just change `const words = x.split(' ');` to `const words = x.split(/[^a-zA-Z]+/gm);`

Comment: Hi @AsherGarland,

I didn't care about special characters because the question said clearly:
"All letters will be lowercase and all inputs will be valid."

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and object to keep track of highest count and respective word

```js
function high(x){
  let mapper = [...`abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz`].reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
    op[inp] = index+1
    return op
  },{})
  return x.split(' ').reduce((op,inp)=>{
    let currentCount = 0;
    [...inp].forEach(v=>{
      currentCount += mapper[v]
    })
    if(currentCount > op.maxCount){
      op.maxCount = currentCount
      op.word = inp
    }
    return op
  }, {maxCount:0, word:''}).word
}

console.log(high('what time are we climbing up the volcano'), 'volcano'))
```

Comment: Though i am not understaing the [...`abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz`].reduce part

still 
Testing for -> tjqajbudvkxhtrpon nazakuthuczkvbwkl lyhvlqigrhhexfrlr cbjsnmhwaadsevajr

Expected: 'tjqajbudvkxhtrpon', instead got: 'nazakuthuczkvbwkl'

Its got only wrong answer on this one.

Plz help me to understand [...`abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz`].reduce part.T

hank you

Comment: @MustafizurRahmanChoudhury i got all the test cleared on codewars with this solution only, the part you are is used to create a mapping object like `{a : 1, b : 2 ..., z: 26 }`

Comment: @MustafizurRahmanChoudhury i tried just now as well, it passes all the tests on codewars

Comment: Ok got it. Do you have any idea why my code is getting wrong there???

Comment: @MustafizurRahmanChoudhury you're using charCodeAt which gives asci value not 1 based, so that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to use an array of the alphabet and indexing the character position in it,

```
let al = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.split('')


   function high(x){
     let words = x.split(" ");
     let out = words.map(word => {
     let score = 0;
     let letters = word.split("");
     letters.map(c => {
      score += al.indexOf(c);
     })
     return [word, score];
    });

    out = out.sort((a,b) => { 
      if(a[1] > b[1]) return -1;
      else if(a[1] < b[1]) return 1; 
      else return 0;  });

return out[0][0];
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Using an alphabet array is very clever, but performing a linear-time lookup in your array for every character at `score += al.indexOf(c);` can be optimized away if you instead used a HashTable for O(1) lookup (a standard Javascript object can act as your HashTable).
Also, instead of aggregating using `.map()` you should use `.reduce()`.
In your sort you don't need the if/else, just do `return a[1] - b[1]`. 
This solution appears to be missing the requirement `If two words score the same, return the word that appears earliest in the original string.`

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your `counterValue += splitChar.charCodeAt();` line. I don't understand how `splitChar.charCodeAt()` translates into 1-26 aka a letters position in the alphabet. "Each letter of a word scores points according to its position in the alphabet"

I was able to able to make your code work by doing two things:

1. Add a map to store the value of each letter in the alphabet. I'm sure this can be done many ways but this was my approach:

```
let letterValues = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9, j: 10, k: 11, l: 12, m: 13, n: 14, o: 15, p: 16, q: 17, r: 18, s: 19, t: 20, u: 21, v: 22, w: 23, x: 24, y: 25, z: 26 };
```

2. And then use this in `counterValue += splitChar.charCodeAt();` as `counterValue += letterValues[letter];`

Answer (score 0):

**Idea:**

- Store the score values in a table for easy lookup
- split sentences into words by non-alphabetic characters
- get each word's score by first calculating the individual characters' scores and then summing them together (using reduce).
- Don't forget to sort by original position if scores are the same, do it by keeping track of the original position.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9xkfqh1m/

```js
const ScoreTable = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4,
  "e": 5,
  "f": 6,
  "g": 7,
  "h": 8,
  "i": 9,
  "j": 10,
  "k": 11,
  "l": 12,
  "m": 13,
  "n": 14,
  "o": 15,
  "p": 16,
  "q": 17,
  "r": 18,
  "s": 19,
  "t": 20,
  "u": 21,
  "v": 22,
  "w": 23,
  "x": 24,
  "y": 25,
  "z": 26
};

// non-ascii letters = 0
function CharScore(char) {
  const lowerCaseChar = char.toLowerCase();
  return lowerCaseChar in ScoreTable ? ScoreTable[lowerCaseChar] : 0;
}

function WordScore(word) {
  return word.split("").reduce((score, char) => {
    return score + CharScore(char);
  }, 0);
}

function SplitOnNonAlphabeticCharacters(str) {
  return str.split(/[^a-zA-Z]+/gm);
}

function high(str){
  const scoreObjects = SplitOnNonAlphabeticCharacters(str)        // split into words
  .map((word, index) => {                                         // map our words into an object with its score and original position
    return {
      text: word,
      score: WordScore(word),
      originalPosition: index
    };
  }).sort((word1, word2) => {                                        // sort
    return word2.score - word1.score                                 // highest score first
                ||  word1.originalPosition - word2.originalPosition; // if score same, earliest original position in string
  });

  return scoreObjects.length > 0 ? scoreObjects[0].text : null;   // return word by the highest score (or earliest original position), or null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The charCodeAt() method returns an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index.

Basically you need to convert it to an uppercase alphabet and subtract the value of the charCodeAt by 64 which will give you the position of the string in the alphabet.

Check this one out:

```js
function high(x) {
    let splittedArray = x.split(' ');
    let splitChar = splittedArray.map(el => el.split(''));
    let charValue = splitChar.map(el => {
        let counter = 0;
        el.map(element => counter += element.toUpperCase().charCodeAt() - 64);
        return counter;
    });
    let largest = 0;
    let largestIndex;
    for (let i = 0; i < charValue.length; i++) {
        if (charValue[i] > largest) {
            largest = charValue[i];
            largestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return splittedArray[largestIndex];
}
```

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Since the characters are guaranteed lower case, it might be easier not to uppercase them, and just subtract 96.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake by not counting letters position in the alphabet. If I subtract 96 from ASCII value then it will calculate `a as 1, b as 2......`

So the solution is given below

```
 function high(x){
  let result = '', value =0, counterValue = 0; 

  let splittedArray = x.split(' ');

  splittedArray.map(splitItem => {
    counterValue = 0;

    let splitItemArray = splitItem.split('');

    splitItemArray.map(splitChar => { 
      counterValue += splitChar.charCodeAt()-96; // if I subtract 96 then it will calculate a as 1, b as 2......
    })

    if(counterValue>value){
      result = splitItem;
      value = counterValue;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function high(x){
const str = x.split(' ');
const result1 = [];
const result = str.reduce((_, dig) => {
  let c = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < dig.length; j++) {
    c = c + (dig.charCodeAt(j) - 96);
  }
  result1.push(c);
}, 0);
return str[result1.indexOf(result1.slice().sort((a, b) => b - a)[0])];
}
```

Comment: _What does this code do?_ Read [answer] and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post since I solved it, even though the post is pretty old. Anyway this was solved from pure javascript.

```
//This main function loops thru each sum from the helper function and returns the position of the highest scoring word

function highestScoringWord(sentence) {
let arr = []
let sentenceSplit = sentence.split(' ')
for(i=0; i<sentenceSplit.length; i++) {
arr.push(scoringWord(sentenceSplit[i]))
}
let max = arr[0]
for(x=0; x<arr.length; x++) {
    if(arr[x] > max) {
        max = arr[x]
    }   
}

for(p=0; p<arr.length; p++) {
    if(max === arr[p]) {
        return sentenceSplit[p]
    }
}

}

//Helper function that takes a word, splits it, and sums up the numbers that each letter is worth.

function scoringWord(word) {
 let wordSplit = word.split('')
 let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
 let sum = 0
 for(j=0; j<word.length; j++) {
     sum+=alphabet.indexOf(word[j])
 }
 return sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function high(x){
const ScoreTable = ["0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k","l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w","x", "y", "z"];

```
return x.split(" ").map(word => {
    let code = 0
    word.split("").map(letter => code += ScoreTable.indexOf(letter))
    return [word, code]
}).sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1])[0][0]
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).